# Using .match() inside of a block

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to read a file and create an array of twitter handles. The file is a random collection of trending tweets, a snippet would be:

> @David_Cameron @britishchambers #BCCConf Mention of pay rises in the
>   NHS. But what about all the redundancies to enable these pay rises?

in which case the code should return

```
["@David_Cameron", "@britishchambers"]
```

Placing `/@\w+/.match(word)[0]` works in irb, but as soon as I put it in a block with `each` or `map`:

```
def read_file(file_path)
  text = File.open(file_path, 'r'){ |f| f.read}.split(" ")
  text.each{|word| /@\w+/.match(word)[0] }
end
```

then I receive the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, if I can do this inside the `file.open` block, that would be preferable.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: @Emily You should update the question rather than stuffing stuff into comments.

Comment: You should accept an answer if at least one is of value.  However, there is no rush to do so.  Selecting an answer too quickly may discourage other answers and it is a courtesy to give people time to complete there answers before one is selected.  Many SO members wait at least a few hours before making a selection. When it comes time to making a selection, choose the one you find most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def read_file(file_path)
  text = File.read(file_path)
  text.scan(/@\w+/).flatten
end
```

Read the file, then use [`#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) to extract all the occurrences.

Comment: That almost works Simone, but it's returning the text without the @ symbol which I still need. Just tried it without the parentheses and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

By placing `[]` after `/@\w+/.match(word)`, you are assuming that `word` always matches `/@\w+/`, thereby returning a `MatchData` object, which is not true. For example `#BCCConf`, does not match `/@\w+/`, in which case `/@\w+/.match(word)` is `nil`. `[]` is not defined on `nil`.